# combine dendrogram plots and heatmap plots in R

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generating a heatmap that depicts the clusters in a dataset using hierarchical clustering in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831501/generating-a-heatmap-that-depicts-the-clusters-in-a-dataset-using-hierarchical-c)

All
I have a questiona about how to combine two dendrograms and a heatmap and align them into one big image for a dataset.

Here is the description:
I hope to firstly create two dendrograms separatly on the same dataset. 
And then create a heatmap plot on this dataset.
finally, to put them together and plot them into one big image as the following. 
http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/moac/people/students/peter_cock/r/heatmap/published_heatmap.jpg?maxWidth=600&maxHeight=589

I know how to draw them at the same by using ggplots. 
But I hope to create them separately and combine them later. 
Thanks for any comments

Comment: I think `heatmap` does what you want already.  There's also a `heat.map2` I believe.

Comment: @TylerRinker: `heatmap.2`, in the [gplots](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gplots/index.html) package.

Comment: Tyler
Thanks for your comment. 
Yes, I know gplots can do this. 
But I need to know how gplots draws the dendrogram and heatmap together and aligned. 
The reason I want to know is I need to create 3 images: vertical and horizontal dendrograms and heatmap.

All these images can be realigned/reconstruct into one image which I used in a Java program.

Thanks,

Comment: Just look at the code of gplots::heatmap.2()...